# Run CD Command directly on terminal with nodejs

Tags: node.js

is it possible to run the cd command directly at the command prompt with nodejs forcing the prompt to go to the desired folder?

I executed the command in the terminal

[prompt path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hJzd.png)

```
const { execSync } = require("child_process")
execSync('cd folder')
```

but nothing happens, the promp remains in the same folder

Comment: you can do this using a module `process`!

Comment: I tried to do it with process.chdir but it didn't work either, the prompt remains in the same folder